# Suppressing fields of embedded documents inside an array

Tags: mongodb

Here is an example of the situation I am encountering (pretend each school has an array of students and there is only 1 result):

```
db.students.find(_id: { $in: school.students })

{
    _id: 1,
    zipcode: "63109",
    students: [
          { name: "john", school: 102, age: 10 },
          { name: "jess", school: 102, age: 11 },
          { name: "jeff", school: 108, age: 15 }
       ]
}
```

How would I do a similar query that omits the "school" fields from the students array inside students?

For example, how do I make the result look like this?

```
{
    _id: 1,
    zipcode: "63109",
    students: [
          { name: "john", age: 10 },
          { name: "jess", age: 11 },
          { name: "jeff", age: 15 }
       ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like below. Use projection to keep the fields you like.

```
db.students.find({}, {zipcode:1,"students.name" :1,"students.age" : 1})
```

Comment: Not to sound obtuse, but have you tested this? I thought that wasn't possible because students is not an object, but rather than array of objects. Something like 'students.0.name' maybe, but what about ALL students? Could it be 'students.$.name' ?

Comment: Yes I did. It should work with embedded array too. Here is the docs https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#projection-on-embedded-documents-in-an-array

Comment: I had the privilege to test it and it works wonderfully! Thank you! I thought it didn't work and I needed to use projections with MongoDB's aggregate function.